# TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, automation

I have checked manually the x path of this particular link but still it gives me the error.
here is the portion of my code i am getting error in.

```
    element = await page2.$x(`//a[contains(text(),'Enable Account Teams')]`);
    await element[0].click();
    await page2.waitForNavigation();
```

Element is undefined but the Xpath is correct and I have tried it with Katalon recorder it is working there. I have also tried page.waitForXpath() but it is not working either.